# How to better read lines of a file in python

Tags: python, file

Is there a more python friendly way to read 100 lines from a file, other than this way:

```
  f=open(varFilename,"r")
  count=0
  for fileLine in f:
      print fileLine
      count+=1
      if count>100:
          break
```

I just feel like there is a better way than having a count increment and then try and break inside the loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to limit the file object iterator to just 100 lines:

```
from itertools import islice

with open(filename) as f:
    for line in islice(f, 100):
```

Here I'm also using the file object as a [context manager](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example/); the `with` statement ensures the file is closed again when the code block is exited.

If you don't need to limit the number of itertions but only need a counter in a loop, don't use a separate counter. Use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) instead:

```
for i, line in enumerate(f):
    if i > 100:
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to get just the first `n` lines from file object:

```
from itertools import islice

with open(varFilename) as f:
    for line in islice(f, 10):
        #do something here
```

And use [`with`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) statement while handling files:

> It is good practice to use the `with` keyword when dealing with file
>   objects. This has the advantage that the file is properly closed after
>   its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised on the way.